# Proving correctness in formal logic

Tags: proof, formal-methods, post-conditions, hoare-logic, proof-of-correctness

I was wondering if anyone could help me answer this question. It is from a previous exam paper and I could do with knowing the answer ready for this years exam.

This question seems so simple that I am getting completely lost, what exactly is it asking for?

> Consider the following section of code involving integer variables:
>
> ```
> if (i < j) {
>     m = i;
> } else {
>     m = j;
> }
> ```
>
> By stating an appropriate output condition and then verifying the
> correctness of the piece of code, prove that after execution, m is equal to
> the minimum of i and j.

I have got the post condition as:
{m = i ∧ i < j ∨ m = j ∧ j < i}

is this correct? and how do you verify this?

Comment: I hope Attila is around today, he really knows his stuff.  If no one replies you might want to ask him directly if that's possible.

Comment: Your post condition should probably be: m = i ∧ i < j ∨ m = j ∧ j <= i

Comment: Yes you are correct Steve, thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post condition is correct. I personally find the following variant (which is equivalent) more natural though:

```
(i<j → m=i) ∧ (i≥j → m=j)
```

To prove that the program satisfies the post condition you do the following.

1. Note that to make sure the program *always* satisfies the post condition you should use `true` as your pre condition.
2. So you have the following Hoare triple:

   ```
   {true}
   if (i < j) {


       m = i;

   } else {


       m = j;

   }
   {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}
   ```
3. The postcondition needs to hold at the end of both branches, so (according to the standard weakest precondition rule for conditionals) we have

   ```
   {true}
   if (i < j) {


       m = i;
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}     <--.
   } else {                                       |
                                                  |
                                                  |
       m = j;                                     |   copy
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}     <--|
   }                                              |
   {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}  ----------'
   ```
4. Pushing the formula further up according to the weakest precondition for assignment yields

   ```
   {true}
   if (i < j) {

       {(i < j → i = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → i = j)}   <---.
       m = i;                                    | m replaced by i
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}   ----'
   } else {

       {(i < j → j = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → j = j)}   <---.
       m = j;                                    | m replaced by j
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}   ----'
   }
   {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}
   ```
5. At the top of the true branch we know that `i < j`, and at the top of the else branch we know that `¬(i < j)`:

   ```
   {true}
   if (i < j) {
       {i < j}                               (1)  <--- added
       {(i < j → i = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → i = j)}   (2)
       m = i;
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}
   } else {
       {¬(i < j)}                            (3)  <--- added
       {(i < j → j = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → j = j)}   (4)
       m = j;
       {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}
   }
   {(i < j → m = i) ∧ (i ≥ j → m = j)}
   ```
6. What left to show is for any two consecutive assertions, the first assertions implies the second one. (These are usually referred to as "proof obligations".) We have two such obligations: `(1)` should imply `(2)` and `(3)` should imply `(4)`. This is clearly the case.

   -- "qed" :-)